# Is "lessor" used for more than property?

Tags: meaning

Does the term "lessor" refer to only parties that lease property?

All of the definitions I have been researching (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lessor, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3A%20lessor, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lease) have only regarded property leasing.

Is it accurate (in casual use, rather than legal use) to use the term "lessor" to refer to someone leasing, say, building equipment? e.g.

> Lorem Supplies Ltd were the lessors of the cement mixer we used when we made that path.

Comment: Looking for the meaning of a word? Have you tried looking in a dictionary? (Text as I remember one of the banners on the site being. It sounds a bit curt, but I'm suggesting that you should be able to easily answer this yourself. If you have already done dictionary research, and it wasn't conclusive, please edit your post to include your research so that we don't repeat it.)

Comment: What makes you think equipment is not *property*?

Comment: Hi @AndyT, yes, sorry, I didn't mention it in the question, I ask since all of my research has mentioned property, I wondered whether `lessor` is for property only, or whether there is another word like `leasor`, `leaser`.

Comment: @TimLymington Because I can't live in a cement mixer ;). The residential/commercial/industrial definition of property.

Comment: @StuperUser I feel sure that the equipment-leasing industry would use the term *lessor* in its contracts. What alternatives would there be?

Comment: @WS2 that is precisely my question. Voting to close your comment as a duplicate ;)

Comment: @StuperUser In that case I don't understand your question. You appear to accept that *Lessor* is used in formal contracts. Why wouldn't it be used, together with other terms, to describe the same person informally?

Comment: @WS2 The rub is that I have seen it in formal contracts and definitions for real estate and buildings only. I ask whether it is specific to real estate/buildings or for anything that is leased.

Comment: @StuperUser I have answered your question below with a sample contract.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough to be answered.A *lessor* is a party to a *lease*, and a *lease* is a contract for the use of real property, which one *lets* or (in the U.S.), *rents*. If the intent is something other than a lease of real property, the term is *renter* and the reference is to a *rental agreement*. So the building equipment example requires *renter* instead of *lessor*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-W Unabridged (subscription required) provides a second definition for *[lessor](http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/lessor)*:

> **2.** a bailor under a bailment agreement providing a rental for personal property

If I understand your question, no, leases (and therefore lessors) aren't restricted to real estate. It's pretty common to lease automobiles, for example.

Comment: The *Master & Commander* clip has nothing to do with leasing - it's amusing, but the only connection to the question here is that for some speakers, *lessor* and *lesser* are homonyms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample of an [Equipment Leasing Contract](https://www.labexofma.com/pdf/lease_agreement.pdf) which quite clearly refers, as I suspected, to a *Lessor* and a *Lessee*